# Azure endpoint not working

Tags: tomcat, azure, port

I am running a tomcat server on port 8111 on an azure Tomcat-LAMP instance. Everything is working but I cannot acces the tomcat from outside the ssh. I added the endpoint 8111-8111

So if I run `telnet localhost 8111` on te VM I am connected, but when I run `http://myvmurl:8111` I get timed out

Does anyone know how to solve this please

Comment: Have you added endpoint to your VM?

Comment: yes:  I added the endpoint 8111-8111 public-private

Answer (score 0):

Another one with public port issues. Did you check whether your local firewall, your router, your corporate sys-admin and your ISP are not blocking outgoing port 8111. Can you confirm at 100% that you can access any other Internet endpoint over port 8111?

99% of these issues are indeed **outgoing** port restrictions, and not Azure misconfiguration behavior. The rest 1% is actually local service configuration issue. For example you try `localhost 8111`, but did you try the direct IP address? Linux images do not have any firewall rules by default (IPTABLES), but does your Tomcat bind to all IP address or just the 127.0.0.1 ? Your VM has a direct IP Address, you can get it with `ifconfig` on linux and `ipconfig` on Windows. All Windows images come with Windows firewall enabled by default that restricts all incoming connections, but Remote Desktop and Remote Powershell.